# Why do I get a target of "undefined" from this `phx-change` event?

Tags: phoenix-live-view

I've got a `<select>` in a LiveComponent and I want to react to the value being changed. There's no submit button. I have this:

```html
<form>
  <select phx-change="per_page_changed" phx-target={@myself} >
    <option value={3}>3</option>
    <option value={5}>5</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

When I change the value, my component's `handle_event` is called, but the params are `%{"_target" => ["undefined"]}` - no value from the `select`. What I am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

### Add a `name` attribute

The `<select>` needs a `name` attribute, like this:

```html
<form>
  <select name="per_page" phx-change="per_page_changed" phx-target={@myself} >
    <option value={3}>3</option>
    <option value={5}>5</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Without a `name` attribute, LiveView doesn't know what key to use for the input value. With `name="per_page"`, the params to `handle_event/3` are `%{"_target" => ["per_page"], "per_page" => "5"}`.